# Django template exercise giving error

Tags: python, django

I am trying to practice an example from Madtering Django on templates
The example tries to explain how dots can refer to methods of objects,can i avoid the error?
This is my input

```
from django.template import Template, Context
t = Template('{{var}} -- {{var.upper}} -- {{var.isdigit}}')
```

The error I get and the end Says

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting TEMPLATES, but settings are configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Please keep in mind I am beginner, Thank you for your answer

Comment: You haven't set your DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable yet, meaning Django does not know what settings to use. Read more at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/#the-django-admin-utility

Comment: Are you the commands in ./manage.py shell or just the normal python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are presumably running this in a plain Python shell. You need to start the shell via `manage.py shell` instead.